# How do I read string as date using Spring + Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

My Hibernate named query calls a stored procedure which returns a date as a formatted string (e.g. "2017/03/15") as one of its columns.

```
<sql-query name="myReportQuery">
    <return alias="myReportQuery" class="com.example.report.ReportLine" />
    { call sproc_report( :fromDate, :toDate) }
</sql-query>
```

Sample output from callilng stored procedure:

```
Date        Item    Price  Qty
----        ----    -----  ---
2017/01/22  Banana  0.75   10
2017/02/15  Apple   1.00   5
2017/02/25  Pear    1.50   8
2017/03/05  Apple   1.00   15
```

Trouble is that I would like to store this field as a Date instead of a String.

```
public class ReportLine {
    private Date date;
    private String item;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private int quantity;
}
```

Is there any way for me to do this?

For reference, I am using Java 6 and Hibernate 3.5.

Comment: Couldn't you make string-to-date/date-to-string conversion in your getter and setter methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple code in setter may work:

```
String sDate1="31/12/1998";  
Date date1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate1);
```

Comment: I ended up using a variant of your solution.

Comment: Yes, you just needed to alter it a little bit (yyyy/mm/dd) I guess!

Answer (score 0):

One of the constructors for the `Date` class is `Date(int year, int month, int day)`.

So you can take your formatted string, split it with `String.split("/")`, and extract the appropriate fields to use in the constructor.

Comment: While this will work, don't re-invent the wheel. SimpleDateFormat will handle conversions.

Comment: My hexagonal wheels will catch on someday.